# php Filemtime function showing wrong date

Tags: php

I would like to add the last modified date to the index page , the below code shows the 31/12/1969 is the last modified date.

```
echo date("d/m/Y",filemtime("index.php"));
```

Comment: Please show `var_dump(filemtime("index.php"));`  - suspect you'll find it says `bool(false)`. Make sure that `index.php` is the correct relative path to the file you are look for the modified time of.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the path is wrong. At last on your development system you should increase the error settings.

In case of an erro [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/filemtime) returns `false`, what what gets casted into `0` by the `date()`-call.

You should refer your files on the filesystem using (pseudo-)absolute paths.

```
__DIR__ . '/path/to/index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `filemtime` is not finding your file. `filemtime` will return 0, or something that equates to 0 like FALSE, and then applying `date` on time `0` will return 0 seconds since the epoch (1st Jan 1970).

Looks like that's what you're getting. I'm also guessing you're using PHP <= 5.1.

Comment: my php version is 5.3.. i given absolute path but till t shows an error

Comment: @BalluRocks Probably something to do with PHP returning negative numbers for pre-epoch times. I'd suggest DaveRandom's approach and dump out the result of filemtime and see what it says. If it's false, then it's still a path issue.