# The PHP function filemtime returning a negative value or very large value

Tags: php, filemtime

I am creating a WordPress plugin and can see that on some servers, for certain files, the [`stat`](http://php.net/stat) (or [`filemtime`](http://php.net/filemtime)) returning invalid *mtime* value. In some cases it is a negative value or a very large value (more than 3 billion).

In FTP I can see that the timestamp is correct though.

Comment: +3bill isn't too likely, unless you're on a 64bit system. +3 bill is impossible for a standard signed 32bit timestamp, and would correspond to ~2065 anyways if you are in 64bit territory.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718772/php-filemtime-function-showing-wrong-date

Comment: ... American or English billions?

Comment: The filepath is surely correct. When I overwrite the file, the timestamp is getting reported correctly. I am guessing the 3billion+ is correlated to the negative value where the highest order bit is being interpreted incorrectly. What I don't follow is, how can the highest order bit get set?

Comment: This should trigger some warnings though; have you set error_reporting to the highest level?

Comment: The question that should be asked is, are you on a windows system or a unix system?

Comment: What file system are you using? NTFS, ext3/4, ReiserFS, tempfs??? This matters. PHP's file system functions are known to have strange behavior on certain systems. This is because some file systems store/interpret `mtime` very differently.

Answer (score 11):

When you get Negative numbers in any PHP timestamp its just the amount of seconds before the Unix Epoch and this is not limited to `filemtime`

**Example A**

```
echo strtotime("1950-1-1"); // Outputs  -631155600
                                        ^------- negative value
```

**Example B**

Outputting negative values does not mean you can not format it correctly  if you try

```
echo date("Y-m-d",-631155600); // Output  1950-01-01
```

**Lastly**

`FTP I can see that the timestamp is correct though`

Your FTP application is definitely not PHP and has its own internal date system .. its Date System might not use negative values in timestamp

Comment: thats a very old server if it has files modified before 1970 :)

Comment: It can be wrong system configurations when the files where created

Comment: Would you know why the timestamp is becoming very large?

Comment: @akshat how large ... give a sample value

Comment: @baba 3421738619 this is one of the values we got

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, a very large value is what you're looking for- this is a Unix Time Stamp.

Did you try something like this?

```
date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename))
```

`filemtime` returns the number of seconds that have passed since January 1, 1970, which should be a very large value indeed; it's up to you to convert those seconds into something human-readable, using something like the above example.

If, on the other hand, you're aware of this and you believe your large value is still wrong, it may be helpful to post an example of said value, along with the date you're expecting for it.

Comment: Large, yes. Over three billion, no.

Comment: @Kolink, certainly not over three billion, but likely over one billion, if I'm not mistaken. Figured the "3 billion" may have been a miscalculation, as `filemtime` returning anything else seems unlikely.

Comment: I understand the timestamp is the "number of seconds since 1970". However, it should not get so large a value. For example, I am getting the value: 3421738619

Answer (score 0):

When your server run a ntp daemon this could be a result of setting the time within a request. This happens e.x. for apache logs and other things that rely on unix system functions, too.

Answer (score 0):

What size are the files that return a negative value for filemtime?

It says here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php that "Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB."

Answer (score 0):

The current value of the unix timestamp is about 1,356,197,722 so a billion is reasonable.

Though it's unlikely to be the issue, it is worth knowing about http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php and using it before calling filemtime().